# How to use user roles with auth component in laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 auth . I have groups table , which defines user groups. My question here is :

Is there a way to use user groups with larvel auth ? If not then please suggest me what should i do to accomplish this .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are several Laravel-specifical packages that you can use to solve this task:
- Sentry 2 https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry (Docs: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry)
- Confide https://github.com/Zizaco/confide
- plus others, but Sentry and Confide are the most popular

Comment: PS: Ofcourse you can also  do it yourself: http://ollieread.com/blog/2014/03/18/a-simplified-laravel-acl/

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Auth functionality is purely to check if the user is valid / logged in. It doesn't provide any role or group management. This would be something you'd need to build yourself.

You can use Laravel's `Auth::user()` method to access data about the logged in user, which you can then use to check what a group a user is in and if they have required access.

In your application's controllers you can define what group access is required to do certain actions.

There is a Laravel package that may help you with a role based structure: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust